# Ruby on Rails Boolean Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean

How can I pass a boolean value in a form to a controller without the user being able to see or edit it? I'm assuming hidden_field is used for this, but how can I then assign a value to the variable?

Thanks for the help
-Pat

Comment: Don't trust that a value won't be modified by the user just because it's hidden in a form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pat,

I am slightly confused by what you mean with the 'but how can I then assign a value to the variable', but I'll give this a go.

First off, you are correct in the hidden_field bit.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'some_name', true %>
```

or, alternatively

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'some_name', false %>
```

You get the point with that, I'm sure.

From there, in your controller, when the form is submitted you would get the value of that field like so:

```
some_boolean = params[:some_name]
```

Obviously variable names would be different, but that's the general gist of it all.

Good luck!

Comment: sorry I wasn't very clear, I had a mysql field that was susposed to take a boolean value and depending on the form I wanted to assign it true or false. I ended up using a radio button that wasn't rendered on the page that had the correct value to pass into mysql.
Thanks for the help though.